# SQL Server 2005 SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey all, this is my query string here:

```
 SELECT SUM(Total) as Total, AdministratorCode, SUM(WOD.Quantity) as thePass 
 FROM   tblWO as WO, 
        tblWOD as WOD
 WHERE WOD.OrderID = WO.ID 
 AND WO.OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-08-31' 
 AND Approved = '1' 
 ORDER BY WO.AdministratorCode
```

But i keep getting the error:

> The multi-part identifier "tblWOD.Quantity" could not be bound.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

David

**SOLVED!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUM(WOD.Quantiy)` (or maybe Quanti**t**y unless the column name is missing a `t`)

You have aliased the table here `tblWOD as WOD` so you have no table with the exposed correlation name `tblWOD`

Comment: Ahhh a double whammy! Miss-spelled Quantity AND AS name! Thanks Martin! :o)

Answer (score 2):

In your Select clause, use just: `SUM(Quantiy)` rather than `SUM(tblWOD.Quantiy)`.  `SUM(WOD.Quantiy)` should also work

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might need something like this

```
SELECT
    SUM(Total) as Total,
    WO.AdministratorCode,
    SUM(WOD.Quantity) as thePass
FROM tblWO as WO, tblWOD as WOD
WHERE
    WOD.OrderID = WO.ID
    AND WO.OrderDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-08-31'
    AND [TableReference].Approved = '1'
Group By WO.AdministratorCode
ORDER BY WO.AdministratorCode
```

Comment: 1. Out of curiosity, why would you answer a question that's already been successfully answered? 2. What is [TableReference]?

Comment: 1) Maybe I didn't notice it had been answered.  [TableReference] is because I don't know which of the 2 tables has the column Approved.